# Image change on mouseover in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, hover

**EDIT 10:04 PM I RESOLVED THIS**

Yeah I figured this out, but the forum software here doesn't let me post an answer to my own question until 8 hours have elapsed.  Anyway, I found the solution [here](http://www.spiceupyourblog.com/2009/10/how-to-make-rollover-mouse-over-image.html).  It uses a pure HTML approach and I tested it successfully in all 5 browsers.  Just had to put in the HTML:  `<img src="starter1.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='starter2.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='starter1.jpg'" />`

---

I'm trying to set up a page (eventually several pages) featuring this:

1) A default image loads when the page loads.
2) When you mouse over, a slightly different image loads.
3) When you move away from that, it goes back to the original image.

I figured this was easy with a little CSS, and it is, except when it comes to Internet Explorer.  Here's what I have (it just shows 2 pictures of a broken starter from my car):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #pic1
            {
                width:500px;
                height:500px;
                background:url("starter1.jpg")no-repeat;
            }
            #pic1:hover
            {
                background:url("starter2.jpg")no-repeat;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="pic1"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works just fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera, but not in Internet Explorer 8.  In fact, in IE8, neither image loads.  I just get a blank white screen.  Am I missing a detail?  Is there a way to get this to work on all browsers?  I read something about wrapping it in an anchor tag but that didn't do anything either.

EDIT:

I can't seem to comment on any post without the code looking terrible, so here goes.  I tried this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #pic1
        {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background:url(starter1.jpg);
            no-repeat;
        }
        #pic1:hover
        {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background:url(starter1.jpg);
            no-repeat;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pic1"></div>
</body>
 </html>
```

Now the first image shows up but the hover over image doesn't.  IE keeps telling me "To protect your security, Internet Explorer has blocked this website from displaying content with security certificate errors." as soon as I open up (IE, before going to the page with my pictures), then asks if I want to view only content that was delivered securely.  I always just say "No".

Lastly, if I try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    #pic1
    {
          background: #FFFFFF url(starter1.jpg) no-repeat fixed center;
    }
    #pic1:hover
    {
          background: #FFFFFF url(starter2.jpg) no-repeat fixed center;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pic1"></div>
</body>
```

I get nothing at all, no images of any kind in any browser.

Comment: Use Firebug if you are trying to troubleshoot these issues, firebug is an amazingly helpful tool, you can also just right click and inspect element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use proper syntax. Here is the proper syntax.

element {

background:

```
#fff

url(image.png)

no-repeat

20px 100px

fixed;
```

}

Notice there are no double quotes ("")

Comment: Thanks.  I made some edits above because the formatting in these comment boxes sucks.  It's still not working.

Comment: If you can put this up on jsfiddle.net i could take a look and let you know where your mistake is.